# Как средствами php или js из ссылки получить html код страницы

Tags: php, javascript

Допустим у меня есть ссылка на страницу, я запускаю скрипт и у меня в переменную попадает html код этой страницы.

Возможно ли это решить средствами js или php?

Comment: На `js` даже если можно, но очень сложно. На `php` вообще не проблема и вариантов полно, начните с изучения документации и ответа @Viktor Izhokin

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

В переменную $html попадет исходный код. Для большинства фреймворков есть более высокоуровневые обвязки.
Подробнее тут:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

На js нужно использовать `AJAX` запрос. При его помощи можно легко отправить `GET` запрос по указанной ссылке, в результате получив HTML в виде строки.

Если вы используете [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) (так удобнее), то можно использовать следующий код (в переменной result будет html):

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/mysite/file.html",
    success : function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Если вы используете чистый Javascript, то надо смотреть сюда: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Примерный код с использование `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Результирующий html будет в переменной `xmlhttp.responseText`.